# Find all connected sets containing $z=i$ on which $f(z)=e^{2z}$ is one to one.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to find all connected sets containing $z=i$ on which $f(z)=e^{2z}$ is one to one.
I have no idea how to approach. 
Can someone give me some hints?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can we fail injectivity? If we have $f(a + ib) = f(c + id)$, then by considering the moduli, we have $e^{2a} = e^{2c} \implies a = b$. So, $a = c$, and
$$e^{2ib} = e^{2ic} \implies \cos(2b) + i \sin(2b) = \cos(2c) + i \sin(2c).$$
From equating real and imaginary parts, we must have $c - d = k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, the only way we could possibly fail injectivity is if we have $z$ and $z + k\pi i$ in the set for some $z \in \mathbb{C}$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, we are looking for connected subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, containing $i$, for which this property does not hold. Unfortunately, there's a lot of such sets, and describing them is not easy. We can start with a class of "obvious" such sets: the strips
$$\lbrace x + iy \in \mathbb{C} : y \in [t, t + \pi), x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$$
for $t \in (1 - \pi,1]$. We can extend this by including any continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $f(0) = 1$ in the following way:
$$\lbrace x + i(f(x) + y) \in \mathbb{C} : y \in [t - \pi / 2, t + \pi/2), x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$$
for $t \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. In fact, $f$ doesn't even need to be continuous necessarily. It will suffice to have the property that, for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, the minimum distance from the set of cluster points of the function as $x \rightarrow y^-$ to the set of cluster points of the function as $x \rightarrow y^+$ is less than $\pi$.

Then there's other variations we could explore. We could take the strip idea and change which side is closed and which is open:
$$\lbrace x + iy \in \mathbb{C} : y \in (t, t + \pi], x \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace$$
for $t \in [1 - \pi,1)$. The same could be extended using a function $f$ as above. Plus, we can even make other hybrid choices. For example, let,

$$S_x = \left \lbrace\begin{array}{ccl} \lbrace x + iy : y \in [t, t + \pi)\rbrace & \text{if} & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ \lbrace x + iy : y \in (t, t + \pi]\rbrace & \text{if} & x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{array}\right.$$
and consider $\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} S_x$ for $t \in (1 - \pi,1]$, or indeed substituting $\mathbb{Q}$ with any set containing $0$.

Basically, there are a lot of such sets. Maybe the best way to describe them is the way I did in the first paragraph: all connected subsets of $D \subseteq\mathbb{C}$, containing $i$, with the property that, for all $z, w \in D$,
$$\frac{z - w}{i\pi} \notin \mathbb{Z}.$$

Sorry I couldn't have been more help. :-P

Answer (score 0):

***Hint:***

$$ f(z)=f(w) \hspace{2mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{2mm} e^{2(z-w)}=1 \hspace{2mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{2mm} 2(z-w) \in 2\pi i \mathbb{Z} \hspace{2mm}\Rightarrow\hspace{2mm} z-w=\pi i k \text{ for some }k \in \mathbb{Z}.$$